# Load sharing IRFP260N MOSFETs

Tags: transistors, mosfet, resistors

I'm trying to load share four parallel [IRFP260N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP260N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628a2ef1fe4) MOSFETs in linear mode. I matched the gates as close as possible.

If I use resistors on the gates, how should I determine the resistors to be used?

I have googled this and haven't come to a definite answer. I see some people use a 3.5 Ω resistor, some people use 5 Ω.

Comment: What power level, amplifier class, frequency range / center and bandwidth, etc.?

Comment: Beware of the sperito effect which will make you miserable .Could you connect the power fets in series ?more circuitry but much better thermal stability.

Comment: Please post a schematic of your amplifier circuit.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a schematic

Comment: I can make a YouTube video and post a link to the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable method of assuring equal current sharing in MOSFETs as well as BJTs is a source or emitter resistor. But you lose efficiency. If this is a switching application, where gate voltage is well above threshold, current will be shared according to the Rds(on) specification, and if one device draws more current, it will heat up and tend to have higher resistance.

(edit) For a linear amplifier, the dissipation of source resistors might not be a major issue. Otherwise, perhaps you could try a voltage divider on each gate to match the threshold voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuAwi3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The simulation shows how two MOSFETs with widely different threshold voltages can be biased to share current equally into a load.

[image: Input and output voltage]
[image: Source currents]

Comment: I'm running the dissipation at 50 volts and the gate at 500mv  I tested and the gate voltage is 3.11v to 3.13v  between the 4   I'm just trying to get them to share a close as possible  to produce 1000w of power output  I can achieve this with 2 but they tend to get hot and not very reliable  I could run the dissipation at 90vdc but my other electronics are only good for 50vdc

Comment: I'm using the fets  to make a linear amplifier  I have a test subject now I have the gate set to 650mv and the dissipation set at 50vdc and I drive it with 10 to 15 watts of RF input and I'm getting 900 watts output with 4 fets into a dummy load  now this is with irfp260n that were perfectly matched  now the supplier is not sending fets that are even close some have 1.7vdc to 4vdc on the gates so if I uses a fet with 1.7v gate and a 2.3 v the 1.7 will be doing most of the work and burn up  before the 2.3 even starts to activate

Answer (score 1):

Mismatches in Vgs are the most important factor when paralleling MOSFETs. It's also important to thermally couple the devices. The specific value of an external gate resistor is not that critical as long as you match them to 1% or use 1% resistors. The value you choose will affect gate turn on time due to the gate capacitance. Any value from about 5 to 15 Ω will work fine.